# A mac application the get requests-as a server

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing in `Obj-C` and `swift` for a very long time .
I would like to do something that i have never done before and i wonder just how to start.

So i would like to have a mac with an app,and that app have its own address, and can get http requests from anywhere on the globe. thats it.

```
http://someStaticName/someProtocol
```

I just need an app with a method that is always running,and can get multiple http requests. *Then in that method i will do my stuff .*

1. How should i create that basic app/method- that has a static address , that you can connect to, and build http protocol over it ? is it have a frameworks?
2. Can i then put that mac app on any kind of server ?

(reason that i am doing server side on `obj-C/Swift` is because thats what i know, and i really need it now-in order to create some server script )

Comment: You might want to start over at [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/newcomers.html) if you're actually considering trying to change the accepted standards that are currently in wide use today.

Comment: What you mean by changing the standards? (i need to write a server application that get none ssl request and turn it into ssl. using stunnel and other services requires knowledge that i dont have)

Comment: Why not just use `localhost`  — seems the most logical to me.

Comment: What is local host? I need my code running and that i can then put on real server..

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I expect you have been downvoted as you don't appear to even know the first thing about the technology you are interested in.  You say you don't know what `localhost` means (not that mentioning it makes any sense at all) and therefore don't even know the basics of networking.  You can, of course, create an HTTP server using Objective-C/Swift, you need to start learning about networking (TCP and ports) and their API (sockets) and then higher level protocols (HTTP and encryption). Then you need to understand the structure of server (threads/forking) and the basic loop.

Comment: @Droppy ok great. So lets make the assumption that i ask a question without knowing too much about it. So what ? is it hurt somebody? do i have to adapt my self to this cubic narrow thinking that you must know everything about the topic being asked ? what if you have a genius project and you are trying to only achieve a specific thing to make it happen? without learning about the atom structure ? common, get out of this software narrow thinking, people can ask and do what ever they want, and its legitimate always. No one is bound to yours or other people's rules if he does something unique.

Comment: Yes you are bound by rules; the rules of stackoverflow which is about providing solutions to specific programming problems.  You don't have a specific programming problem to solve and therefore your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Droppy, well , i am not bound to any of your/website rules. This is why i am doing big things in my life, and not just writing lines of code.

Comment: They aren't my rules; they are the rules of stackoverflow.  If you don't like them then don't use the site.

Comment: I am not sure you really got the deep meaning of what i have just said. but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found  a great and simple way to do this with  `CocoaHTTPServer`

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer